# Adding new entry on the GRUB on CentOS Stream 8

Tags: centos, grub

I want to add new entry into `grub2` menu on `CentOS Stream 8`

I set the following contents to
/etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=160M resume=/dev/mapper/<myuser>-swap rd.lvm.lv=<myuser>/root rd.luks.uuid=luks-309cf5fa-bd51-4229-9f90-7e38e600beb6 rd.luks.uuid=luks-685fc7dd-38a2-4697-8a49-fece38a7d4e8 rd.luks.uuid=luks-6ac6ae2a-ecea-4752-9df9-497eeaa42595 rd.luks.uuid=luks-e3e4bb6c-241f-430f-94d8-a149d2a845e9 rd.lvm.lv=aabor/swap rhgb quiet intel_iommu=on vfio-pci.ids=10de:1e07,10de:10f7,10de:1ad6,10de:1ad7 rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau nouveau.modeset=0"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=true
```

I want to add `MemTest86` to grub menu, here are my preparations:

```
# copy the locally created /EFI/BOOT directory to system’s EFI boot
sudo cp -r ~/iso/memtest-temp/EFI/BOOT/ /boot/efi/EFI/memtest86

sudo nano /etc/grub.d/40_custom
menuentry 'MemTest86' {
  insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    set root='hd4,gpt1'
    chainloader ($root)/EFI/memtest86/BOOTX64.efi
}

sudo grub2-mkconfig --output=/boot/grub2/grub.cfg
sudo reboot now
```

The system boots as usual, since I encrypted my drive I have to enter valid password and it works fine, but nothing happens with GRUB menu, no new entry is shown.

What is the correct way to add new entry in grub menu on `CentOS Stream 8`?

Answer (score 0):

I think `40_custom` is a shell script, you cannot just put menuentry like that. In my debian box, the `40_custom` file has following codes in it, you may try add these lines before your menuentry.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
```